# Undefined reference to KWallet

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator, qmake, kde-plasma

I keep getting this undefined reference:

```
error: undefined reference to `KWallet::Wallet::openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long long, KWallet::Wallet::OpenType)'
```

Source code  :

```
#include <KWallet/Wallet>

WId wid = 0;
Wallet* wallet = Wallet::openWallet(Wallet::NetworkWallet(),wid,Wallet::Synchronous);
```

.pro file:

```
...
LIBS += #-lgnome-keyring \
        -lglib-2.0 \
        -lkdecore \
        -lkdeui \
        -lkparts

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 \ 
               /usr/include/glib-2.0  \
               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include \
               /usr/include/KDE
...
```

I think I have linked all required libs, don't know where the mistake could be.

Answer (score -1):

I found this on

http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kwallet/html/namespaceKWallet.html

```
QT += KWallet
```

you could also try

```
LIBS += -lkwallet
```

and see if it that helps.